# What Data Type is Used for the Size of a Plot of Land?

Tags: types, uml

In a UML Diagram for housing development, I need to add data types for the plot size. Would it be a string data type? Or, would it be labeled as "real"?

Comment: What ever is useful for you. Square-somthing. Vectors surrounding it. ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to calculate with it, it should be a number. So, real is an obvious choice. Of course, you would need to specify the unit. There is no standard way in UML to do that. SysML however, has value types, that allow to specify units for value specifications.